# Storing array in db

Tags: php

I need to create an array of keys and store it in a db table.

```
$myArr = array();

foreach($keys AS $key) {
    $myArr[$r->id] = $r->key;
}
```

before storing it I serialize it

```
$db_arr = serialize($myjArr);
```

Later I need to get the stores array and loop through it to perform some action. However, when I unserialize stored array and do **print_r** my output looks like this:

```
Array ( [5981] => 7u7Dj [5982] => mVmx4 )
```

It appears that the array is malformed. What am I missing?

Comment: Where is $r defined?  Is this your real code?  It's never too late to read [mcve]

Comment: It "appears malformed", but is it though? Have you even tried to `unserialize` it?

Comment: What does the original array look like?

Comment: I create an array myself through the loop above. $r is a part of my data object. The unserialized output is the last line of code in my post: Array ( [5981] => 7u7Dj [5982] => mVmx4 )

Comment: Sorry, but I just don't understand what the problem is. That looks identical to the array in the question. In what way is it malformed?

Comment: A [mcve] really would help.  "It doesn't work for me, but I won't give you enough code to reproduce my results" is not a well-written question for SO.  (I'm not one of the downvoters though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at this, I think you may need to unserialize the data before trying to use it [php unserialize](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.unserialize.php)

```
$array = unserialize($serialized_array);
```

Here is an example

```
$original = [
  "who" => "you",
  "me" => "yes"
];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($original);
echo "</pre>";

$ser = serialize($original);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($ser);
echo "</pre>";

$un = unserialize($ser);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($un);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Yeah you right I updated the response. By the way using json_encode and json_decode should do the JOB. Tks for dowvote

Comment: My unseralized output looks like this: Array ( [5981] => 7u7Dj [5982] => mVmx4 ) .

Comment: Are you sure. I just updated my answer by adding an example and it works perfect